# string parameter sent via AJAX to controller not hitting

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

trying to make an AJAX call to a c# controller

my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult checkEmail(string email)
{
    var emails = emails.GetByEmail(email);
    if (emails != null)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false });
    } else {
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
}
```

my ajax call:

```
var checkEmails= function (email) {
    /* call the save endpoint */
    console.log(email);
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("checkEmail")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'email': email },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                console.log('doesnt exist');
            } else {

                AlreadyExists();
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, x, y) {
            console.error('failed', xhr, x, y);
        }
    });
}
```

when i use             `data: { 'email': email },`

and put a breakpoint on my controller method, it doesnt hit it at all.

but i was to do  `data: Json.stringify(email),`

the breakpoint is hit, but the email value being passed through is null

any ideas?

Comment: Pass JSON (as per accepted answer) or don't tell ajax you're passing JSON, remove: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting an object

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("checkEmail")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'email': email }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: true,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
            console.log('doesnt exist');
        } else {
             AlreadyExists();
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, x, y) {
        console.error('failed', xhr, x, y);
    }
});
```

Change the parameter as an object.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult checkEmail(CheckEmailInput input)
{
    var emails = emails.GetByEmail(input.Email);
    if (emails != null)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false });
    } else {
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
}
```

```cs
public class EmailInput
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have to create an object just for a string?  am i not able to just pass a string, and receive a string?

Comment: The object is necessary as you're sending a key/value pair, not just a string

Comment: *create an object just for a string* no, you have to convert your object to JSON because you're using `contentType:json` so you have to send JSON.  `data: { 'email': email },` is already creating an object (as noted above) key/value with the key to match your action parameter name.